# Class not found Exception in Hazelcast plugin in openfire in cluster environment

Tags: cluster-computing, classnotfoundexception, openfire, hazelcast

I have installed openfire in 3 EC2 instance and added hazelcast plugin in all three. All three nodes work fine. But some time i get this exception in stderror log, Please help me to identify why this exception occurs and how can i avoid this error logs? ? ?

```
Apr 15, 2015 12:16:18 PM com.hazelcast.spi.OperationService
SEVERE: [172.31.22.121]:5701 [openfire] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jivesoftware.util.cache.ClusteredCacheFactory$CallableTask
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jivesoftware.util.cache.ClusteredCacheFactory$CallableTask
  at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.read(Defaul tSerializers.java:190)
  at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAd apter.java:40)
  at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.readObject(Serializati onServiceImpl.java:276)
  at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayOb jectDataInput.java:431)
  at com.hazelcast.executor.BaseCallableTaskOperation.readInternal(BaseCallableTaskO peration.java:91)
  at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.readData(Operation.java:295)
  at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:105)
  at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:36)
  at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAd apter.java:59)
  at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(Serialization ServiceImpl.java:218)
  at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.toObject(NodeEngineImpl.java:156)
  at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.OperationServiceImpl$RemoteOperationProcessor.run(Operat ionServiceImpl.java:724)
  at com.hazelcast.util.executor.ManagedExecutorService$Worker.run(ManagedExecutorSe rvice.java:166)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  at com.hazelcast.util.executor.PoolExecutorThreadFactory$ManagedThread.run(PoolExe cutorThreadFactory.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jivesoftware.util.cache.ClusteredCacheFactory$CallableTask
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:83)
  at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil$1.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:77)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
  at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.read(Defaul tSerializers.java:185)
  ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to deploy some openfire jar inside your Hazelcast cluster. Hazelcast does not offer remote classloading for security reasons (otherwise everybody could inject everything).

Comment: can you please be specific on which jar i have to add in to hazelcast plugin jar and in which location i have to add?

Comment: Node no idea but I would guess something like openfire.jar?

Comment: I restarted all 3 nodes and found that this exception occurs after 2.30 hours and thrown every seconds. Is it something to do with garbage collector? Is it because of clusteredcachefactory class is garbage collected and that's the reason this exception occurs?

Comment: @udhaya Did you solve this problem? I'm facing the very same problem.